# RavenDB Spatial index for LineString

Tags: ravendb, spatial-index

How do I create a RavenDB Spatial Index for LineString geo data ?

I am trying to create a spatial index for LINESTRING of geo data, But search query does not return any data.

Please use following testcase as reference, since I am new to RavenDb I am not sure my search query is correct or bug on RavenDB

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Raven.Abstractions.Indexing;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Embedded;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;

namespace GeoDataLoading.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SpatialTest
    {
        public class GeoDocument
        {
            public string WKT { get; set; }
        }

        public class GeoIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<GeoDocument>
        {
            public GeoIndex()
            {
                Map = docs => from doc in docs
                              select new {_ = SpatialGenerate("WKT", doc.WKT, SpatialSearchStrategy.GeohashPrefixTree)};
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void LineStringsShouldNearest()
        {
            using (var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {RunInMemory = true})
            {
                store.Initialize();
                store.ExecuteIndex(new GeoIndex());

                using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    session.Store(new GeoDocument
                        {
                            WKT =
                                "LINESTRING (-0.20854 51.80315, -0.20811 51.80395, -0.20811 51.80402, -0.20814 51.80407, -0.20823 51.80419, -0.20888 51.80435, -0.20978 51.80455, -0.21033 51.80463, -0.21088 51.80467, -0.2116 51.80463, -0.21199 51.80457, -0.21246 51.80453, -0.2131 51.80448, -0.21351 51.80442, -0.2143 51.80433, -0.21436 51.80372, -0.21454 51.80321, -0.21468 51.80295)"
                        });
                    session.SaveChanges();
                }

                using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    List<GeoDocument> result = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<GeoDocument>("GeoIndex")
                                                      .WaitForNonStaleResults()
                                                      .WithinRadiusOf(1.2, -0.20854f, 51.80315f)
                                                      .SortByDistance()
                                                      .ToList();

                    Assert.IsTrue(result.Count > 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class YourDocumentType_SpatialIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<YourDocumentType>
{
    public SpatialIndex()
    {
        Map = documents => from document in documents
                    select new
                     {
                        document.LinkId,
                        _ = SpatialGenerate(fieldName: "Geometry", shapeWKT: document.Geometry, strategy: SpatialSearchStrategy.GeohashPrefixTree, maxTreeLevel: 12)
                     };
    }
}
```

Fair warning that I have not tested this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But don't think index is working. Following query is not filtering data.

Comment: streets = session.Query<Street>()
                               .Customize(x => x.WithinRadiusOf(10, -4.06011, 51.70934))
                               .ToList();

Comment: @user2144147  you didn't specify the index in the query.  `session.Query<YourObject, YourIndex>()...`  Spatial queries require a static index always.